# Read only opened excel file saved with VBA but is not saved at all?

Tags: excel, vba, readonly, save-as

I have an excel template which is recommended to open as read-only on opening to users (I have the password to open file to be able to change/edit the file).
I have a vba script which saves the read-only opened file.

When I save the file the normal way (menu > save as > choose file > save) excel returns a message telling me the file cannot saved because it is opened as read-only.

When I use the script, a popup shows me the desired directory with the proper filename, and saving is possible (so opened as read-only, it still can be saved with the same filename). No errors at all.

But when I look in the directory now, most of the files I have updated and saved do not have an updated 'last edited date/time'. And when I open the file, all changes I have made are not in the file anymore.

Is it possible that VBA says it has saved the file with the same filename, although the file was opened as read-only, but in fact did not save anything?

here is the save-as code:

```
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)
Dim workbook_Name As Variant

  Windows(mytemplate).Activate

  On Error GoTo Err_

  MsgBox ("Bezig met vernieuwen")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'  Call SheetOpschonen

  Call datawissen
  Call dataplaatsen
  Call kolomtitels
  Call toevoegen
  Call maaktabel
  Call refreshpivots

workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:="M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment ontwikkeling\")

MsgBox workbook_Name

If workbook_Name <> False Then

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbook_Name, FileFormat:=50

End If

Exit_:
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub

Err_:
  Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
  Resume Exit_

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

it seems to work, but as I found out, it does not work when the file is opened as read-only, although I looks like the file is saved and can overwrite the original file while being opened as read-only.

**update 2019-04-11 10:00 AM:**

with the suggestion from ZACK I adjusted my save as code to:

```
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)
Dim workbook_Name As Variant

  Windows(mytemplate).Activate

  On Error GoTo Err_

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'  Call SheetOpschonen

  Call datawissen
  Call dataplaatsen
  Call kolomtitels
  Call toevoegen
  Call maaktabel
  Call refreshpivots

If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite

workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:="M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment ontwikkeling\")

If workbook_Name <> False Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbook_Name, FileFormat:=50


ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly

Exit_:
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub

Err_:
  Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
  Resume Exit_

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

opening a read-only file and saving it while overwriting the original read-only file works. Except for that I know have to enter the filename again. While if before uses the original filename, there is no filename shown in the save as popup screen anymore.

[image: save-as-popup.png]

**update 2 2019-04-11 10:31 AM:**

I had some additional "save as code" for getting the right filename which I used before (was in the original post). I added this code to my main macro and tested if it works. Now the file access is changed correctly, the save as popup shows the correct filename in the right directory and the file is saved.

**Conclusion:** case closed, question answered!

Here is how it works (for me):

```
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)
Dim workbook_Name As Variant
Dim workbookdirectory As String
Dim activewb As String

  Windows(mytemplate).Activate

  On Error GoTo Err_

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'  Call SheetOpschonen

  Call datawissen
  Call dataplaatsen
  Call kolomtitels
  Call toevoegen
  Call maaktabel
  Call refreshpivots

If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite

activewb = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

workbookdirectory = "M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling\"

workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:=workbookdirectory & activewb)

If workbook_Name <> False Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbook_Name, FileFormat:=50

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly

Exit_:
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub

Err_:
  Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
  Resume Exit_

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to verify that the popup from VBA that lets you select a folder is the actual folder the file is saved in. Can you show us the code?

Comment: Change the attribute of the file to `ReadWrite` before attempting to save it

Comment: Why do you have `If workbook_Name = False`  Are you testing to see if the `workbook_Name` exists?

Comment: I copied the save as script from a different question here at stackoverflow or any other excel/vba site for the save as vba script.

Comment: As @Zac mentioned you will need to set the read only attribute to to `vbNormal` when the workbook is opened then when you close the workbook you will need `wb.Close True` (`wb` is however you set the Workbook Object) then set the read only attribute back to `vbReadOnly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other solution you can try is this, which is what Zac was talking about.  It will change the access of the active workbook so you can run your code then change it back to read only.

```
Sub saveas()
Dim workbook_Name As Variant
Dim location As String
Dim workbookdirectory As String
Dim activewb As String
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite     

         activewb = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

         workbookdirectory = "M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling\"

         workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:=workbookdirectory & activewb)

         If workbook_Name = False Then ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:=activewb, FileFormat:=50

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be the right solution. It has to been done when the file is already opened or is being opened. I will implement above code in my save as script.

Comment: my complete code is quiet large (I will not paste it here completely). But do I have to paste all the code at 'run code here' section of the above? And is this instead of my save as code?

Comment: me too, I saw I have the save as code integrated into the main macro. I pasted the main macro in my answer. But your/answer post above makes clear for me what I should test.

Comment: if it works please accept the answer, so if others come across this they will be able to see it.

Comment: tested the method. I now get the error: 1004: Method Changefileacces of object_workbook failed (free translation of dutch error message).

Comment: changed the script to: If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite to test is fileacces is already readonly on opening. after that, the script works. except for that now the original filename is not shown anymore in the save as pop up screen, but saving the file while it was originally opened as read-only is succesfull. Now I still have to find a way to get the originale workbookname in the save as popup screen again. Will add the code to my question.